# insert values through jquery to c# mvc post method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to this and got stuck between these codes without getting inserted. Can anybody pls tell me the issue in my post method.

**jquery**

```
$.post("Create", { REG_NO : $("#text1").val(), REG_DATE : $("#text2").val() }, function (data) {
    alert("done");
});
```

**CarsController (controller file)**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,REG_NO,REG_DATE")] Car car)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Cars.Add(car);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(car);
    }
}
```

**class file**

```
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string REG_NO { get; set; }
    public DateTime REG_DATE { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: are you getting value in Car object in controller ?

Comment: Look at the errors generated in the console! And learn how to construct a url - `var url = '@Url.Action("Create")';`

Comment: @mairaj I'm sorry how to check that.

Comment: Also where is your ID in javascript code ?You have Bind(include ID) but there is no ID passing from javscript.

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page so `return RedirectToAction("Index");` is just ignored, at what would be the point of `return View(car);`? You would be returning exactly what you sent in the first place.

Comment: @mairaj can I bind value like this ..

Comment: $.post("Create", { ID : 10, REG_NO : $("#text1").val(), REG_DATE : $("#text2").val() }, function (data) {
                        alert("done");
                    });

Comment: @StephenMuecke all those codes where generated implicitly. tht returns with currently added data along wth other data

Comment: It does not. You send the data relating to a car from controls on you page, then you return a view of exactly the same car (but don't even do anything with it e.g update the DOM) but since you already have the data on the page the whats the point of your method returning another copy of it. And `return View(car);` returns only one `Car` not _along wth other data_ - there is no other data your returning!

Answer (score 0):

$.post(
    '/controller/action', 
    { field_a: "Value a", field_b: "Value b" }, 
    function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
);